# naural join is giving Cartesian product of two relations

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, cross-join, natural-join

I have two relations, `emp(id,name)` and `emp2(name,city,salary)` with values:

[image]

and relation emp2 values :
[image]

As you can see, when I run natural join between them I get their Cartesian product.
But why, since they have a common attribute (`name`)?

Comment: join with out on clause will give you cartesian product of rows

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: You *are* getting the natural join, not the Cartesian join. What do you think you should get? [mcve] PS [Please do not use images/links when you can use text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Cut and paste all that text please.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* getting natural join, not Cartesian product.

There is one copy of each common column and one copy of each column unique to an input table. There is a row for every different combination of a row from the left input table and a row from a right input table.

If a subrow value (`('kim')`) for common columns (`name`) appears n times in the left table (2 times) and m times in the right table (2 times) then it will appear n times m times in the output (2 times 2 times = 4 times).

An SQL Cartesian product would have columns `name`, `city`, `salary`, `id` & `name` and would have a row for every different combination of a row from the left input table and a row from a right input table.

That includes every possible combination of a `name` value from the left table and the right table. But for this example data there is only *one* `name` value over both tables, so every pair of name values has to have that value twice.

Natural join is the same as Cartesian product followed by restriction on equality of common columns followed by projecting away one of each common column followed by keeping distinct rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have two time the same value in the common column  (name)  so this retrive the rows more  time . 
Your natural join is based on both the table that  have not unique value each row.
Then in this case you get always more that a row for each entry (also with inner join) but you could solve using distinct

```
select dictinct emp.*, emp2.* 
from emp 
inner join emp2 on emp.name = emp2.name
```

or

```
select select dictinct emp.*, emp2.* 
from emp2 natural join emp
```

Comment: I have only one attribute common that is "id"

Comment: you your img i see  table emp2 with id and name  ...same name  =  common attributes

Comment: I think you have misunderstood please see the query above the result relation that is emp2

Comment: yes  .. but i hav fuond the issue  .. answer  updated  with a brief explanation

Comment: Your explanation is poor. You are not using enough words to refer to enough things to say what you mean. Use more sentences and words. Refer to all the parts of things that you need to refer to. Do not rush. I can fix your grammar, but I can't fix what you don't say. You need to say what you mean. PS Check out translate.google.com; lately is has become *much* better via AI.

Answer (score 0):

select * from emp inner join emp2 on emp.id = emp2.id

Comment: This does not answer the question.